# How to achieve Asynchronous Apex with Aura Components? (NOT Callouts)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, governorlimits, future, asynchronous

I have a working Aura Application with a requirement of showing heavy data inside of many lightning datatables based on the LoggedInUser.

It works fine for majority of the users but for few, the data is too much and we hit the governor limits: CPU Execution Time, **Ex: Maximum CPU time: 5232 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT**

The `@future` method doesn't work for me because the Apex Method returns a *Map* of custom Apex Data type.

Is there a way to make my AuraEnabled method(s) ASYNCHRONOUS?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of your code to give a context:

Have you tried giving this a shot:
[Return Result for Asynchronous Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods_async.htm)

If you haven't tried that, I would try implementing it. Your callback should be able to process and render the data. Still says the aura:method executes synchronously though :(

Also came across this: [Make Long-Running Callouts with Continuations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations.htm)

which seems interesting if you were doing a callout.

hope that helps solve your problem!

Comment: I read the first article before posting this question. It might work but wanted to see if there's other ways to achieve this. Also, doc says: JavaScript code that calls a server-side action is **asynchronous**.